# Draw a star on Python's Tk, not shell

Tags: python, tkinter

I am making a program using tkinter.
However, it is displayed on the shell, not on tkinter.

```
def starDrawingA(z):
    for i in range(0, z):
        for j in range(0, z-i):
            print('*', end='')
        print()

def starDrawing1():
    z = int(f1.get())
    f1.delete(0, END)
    str1 = Label(window, text=starDrawingA)
    str1.pack()
    str1.place(x=400, y=230)

f1 = Entry(window)
f1.pack()
f1.place(x=400, y=150)
```

Comment: Perhaps you should return the string, rather than print.

Comment: What's the propose to this code? It seems not clear to me what you want to achieve.

Comment: well, `print` displays text on the console so what did you expect?